# ReactJS and jest: how to use a mock value for element.offsetWidth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a component that programmatically creates a span element and adds text to it, then checks for its `offsetWidth`. Within my tests this value is 0. I would like to know how I can "force" it to another arbitrary value for testing.

I tried with the following with no avail:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', { configurable: true, value: 500 })
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Github: https://github.com/sickdyd/react-dynamic-badge

This is a link to the test file for the component: [https://github.com/sickdyd/react-dynamic-badge/blob/master/src/test/**test**/DynamicBadge.test.js](https://github.com/sickdyd/react-dynamic-badge/blob/master/src/test/__test__/DynamicBadge.test.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I used a technique called dependency injection (https://chipcullen.com/how-to-fake-the-window-object-in-jest-and-enzyme/)

Basically pass a prop for testing and use it within your code:

```
// for testing purposes use props.testRulerSpanWidth
// if it exists, otherwise use the default rulerSpan.offestWidth

const rulerSpanWidth = props.testRulerSpanWidth ?
                        props.testRulerSpanWidth
                       :
                        rulerSpan.offsetWidth;
```